# Is there any way to configure VPN for a chrome driver in selenium automation?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

I'm running automation in which I need to hit an URL that is blocked in a certain region, so I need to configure VPN for the chrome driver while launching it so that I can access the URL. is there any possibility?

I am using Selenium for running my automation.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a project where I will have to solve this in the future.
I will want to run multiple instances of the automation from different VPNs.

Planning to run my [selenium automation in docker](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) containers, each with their own instance of openVPN.

https://hub.docker.com/r/dperson/openvpn-client/

I haven't thought much further yet. 
Hope it helps.